# Forcing figure placement at the top of a particular page

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column

I need to force an image (`compression_strain_map.pdf`) to the top of a particular page (document has two columns) and the text under it. It seems like it only works on one column.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{figure}[tp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6, trim={0cm 1cm 0.75cm 0cm}, clip]{images/compression_strain_map.pdf}&\raisebox{4cm}{\rotatebox{90}{\textit{local Lagrangian vertical strain}}} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Local Lagrangian vertical strain fields with the corresponding absolute values of the global strain $\left|\varepsilon\right|$ for a pure compression test.}
\label{fig:compression_strain_maps}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is when I use `\begin{figure*}` the figure is placed on the next page, but I want to force the figure being on this one.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `figure` is one-column, `figure*` is a two-column span, move it earlier in the source so it comes on the page you want.

Comment: That was simple thanks. I didn't thought of this. I thought that I should put the image after the text I want and then there should be some definition that would force its placement to be exact. Thanks (I know that I look stupid not thinking of that and I've tried many things, but mostly changing the code not its order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`figure` is one-column, `figure*` is a two-column span, move it earlier in the source so it comes on the page you want.

Comment: One more question: In case I have two `figures` and one `table` that should be under both figures and LaTeX puts the table above - no matter where I put the `table` definition. Is there a way to set an order for placement (or force it)?

Comment: You can put the tabular and its caption in the same  `figure*` as the figures, then they float together (use captof package so you can caption teh table with `\captionof{table}{....}`